# Django Paginator Error

Tags: django

I'm been trying to implement django paginator into my whiteboard app so I can split the pictures into different pages.

The problem  occurs when I attempt to move across different pages.I limited each page to 1 objects and uploaded few pictures to test if the pagination works between pages but when I try to move across different pages using the pagination method, it doesn't respond.

http://img854.imageshack.us/img854/3303/94627386.jpg

I'm been researching and testing for solutions to this problems through the django pagination docs and I think problem lay at the pagination module method at my template.

My views.py

```
 def Boat(request ,animal_id):
         if not request.user.is_authenticated():
             return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:LoginRequest'))

    picture = Picture.objects.filter(board=animal_id)

    paginator = Paginator(picture,1)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
             picture = paginator.page(page)

         except PageNotAnInteger:
             picture = paginator.page(1)
         picture = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)


    return render(request,'boat.html',{'picture':picture })
```

My boat.html

```
 {% if picture.object_list %}
 <ul>
    {% for pet in picture.object_list %}


        {% if pet.image %}

    <br>
        <img src= "{{ pet.image.url }}" </a>
 <br>
    </a>
 </li>
        {% endif %}

 <br>
 <a href="{% url world:CommentCreator pet.id %}">View Comment</a>  <a href="{% url      world:LikePicture pet.id %}">Like</a><br/>
 {% for c in picture %}
     {% ifequal c.picture.id pet.id %}

 <br>{{ c.body }}</li>
 <br>{{ c.created}}</li>
 <br>{{ c.user}}</li>
     {% endifequal %}
 % endfor %}

 {% endfor %}
 </ul>
 {% endif %}
 <a href="{% url world:PictureCreator %}">Add Pictures to your board</a><br/>

 {% if number %}
 {{number}}
 {% endif %}
 <a href="{% url world:Profile %}">Return back to Profile</a><br/>

 <br><br><br><br><br>

 <div class="pagination">
     <span class="step-links">
         {% if picture.has_previous %}
             <a href="?page={{ picture.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
         {% endif %}

         <span class="current">
             Page {{ picture.number }} of {{ picture.paginator.num_pages }}.
         </span>

         {% if picture.has_next %}
             <a href="?page={{ picture.next_page_number }}">next</a>
         {% endif %}
     </span>
 </div>
```

Parts of my module

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board,blank=False,null=False,related_name='board')
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/",blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    is_primary = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def Boat(request ,animal_id):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:LoginRequest'))

    picture = Picture.objects.filter(board=animal_id)

    paginator = Paginator(picture,1)

    try:
        page = int(request.GET.get('page', '1'))
    except ValueError:
        page = 1

    try:
        picture = paginator.page(page)
    except (EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
        picture = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    picture = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request,'boat.html',{'picture':picture })
```

Comment: just started now. I'm thinking of what codes I will put in that blog

Comment: cathy do you think their an problem with the pagination method in template?

Comment: yeah, your codes for paginator is incomplete that's why it's not working

Comment: I got it working :) the problem was inside that template and i also used your boat views and combine .:)

Comment: I don't see problem in your template,, I just see incomplete codes in your views

Comment: I forgot hahahah...sorry. I just wake up now because of being tired in cleaning the house. But about what are you saying, my answer above is my pattern in app so maybe you missed something when you copy it

Comment: I will not be answering today. I'm not in the mood.

Comment: It's okay , take a rest buddy :)

Comment: do you want to play this game http://store.steampowered.com/app/62000/?snr=1_7_15__13 
I play it sometimes

Comment: no, I like the games that are challenging, solving mystery, and making strategies. Like solving crimes games, GTA, Dawn of War, DOTA..like that different chapter to play and solve

Comment: How do you normally get games? Do you buy them or torrent them

Comment: from my friends and I don't know how they get it. I don't want to use torrent because they seems to be fake or have virus

Comment: yes, I finish all the chapters, "The Frozen Throne". Is your DOTA, the latest?

Answer (score 0):

```
#this is view 
#this is views files
@login_required(login_url='/login')

# class Base_page_list2(ListView):
def Base_page_list(request,*args, **kwargs):

    # tiket      = Tiket.objects.all()
    
    # lastest_tiket =Tiket.objects.order_by('-id').all()[:8]
    tiket_list = Tiket.objects.all()
    paginator  = Paginator(tiket_list,2)

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page)

    context ={
        'tiket':None,
        'page_obj':page_obj,
        

        
    }
    context['tiket']=['page_obj']
    
    
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        context['tiket']= Tiket.objects.all()
             
    elif not request.user.is_hrm:
        raise Http404('شما نمی توانید به این صحفه دسترسی داشته باشید')
    
    elif request.user.is_mis :
        context['tiket']= Tiket.objects.filter(status_tag='s')
    
    elif request.user.is_mali:
        context['tiket']=Tiket.objects.filter(status_tag='m')
    
    elif request.user.is_mosh:
        context['tiket']=Tiket.objects.filter(status_tag='c')

    elif request.user.is_modir:
        context['tiket']=Tiket.objects.filter(status_tag='b')
    
    elif request.user.is_kz:
        context['tiket']=Tiket.objects.filter(status_tag='k')    
    
    elif request.user.is_pa:
        context['tiket']=Tiket.objects.filter(status_tag='p')  
    
    else:
       context['page_obj']['tiket']=Tiket.objects.filter(author=request.user) 
return render(request,'hrm_account/base.html',context)
`enter code here`error

  File "/home/ali/Desktop/testsharen2/sharen/sharen_hrm/views.py", line 128, in Base_page_list
    context['page_obj']['tiket']=Tiket.objects.filter(author=request.user)
TypeError: 'Page' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).